# CREATE UNIQUE causes duplicate relationships with Neo4j and JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j, acid

One of my bolt in Storm is a module that adds edge on Neo4j.
If I use parallelism I have duplicates. Here's the code:

```
  try {
        Connection connection = getNeo4jConnection();
        try {
            Trip trip = (Trip) tuple.getValueByField("trip");
            try (Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {
                String query = "MATCH (u:Airport {name:'" +
                        trip.getOutgoingAirport() + "'}), (r:Airport {name:'" +
                        trip.getIngoingAirport() + "'})" +
                        " CREATE UNIQUE (u)-[:FLIGHT_TO { amount: '"+ 1 +"' }]->(r)";
                System.out.println("QUERY " + query);
                stmt.execute(query);
            }
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    collector.ack(tuple);
```

I'm experimenting so don't mind the ugly `try catch`, it's not production code.
The connection is created with:

```
private static Connection getNeo4jConnection() throws SQLException {
    Driver driver = new org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver();
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("user", "neo4j");
    properties.put("password", "neo4j");
    String url = "jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/";
    return driver.connect(url, properties);
}
```

As you can see a query is something like: `MATCH (u:Airport {name:'CIA'}), (r:Airport {name:'STN'}) CREATE UNIQUE (u)-[:FLIGHT_TO { amount: '1' }]->(r)`.
Now I would have expected, as you can read on the docs, that neo4j has acid transaction so I would assume that I had no duplicates but I have them when using concurrent bolts. I would assume it's a racing condition because if I use 1 thread, it doesn't happen.

Could you help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can use one connection per thread, so you don't have to recreate them per statement.

Actually there is no uniqueness guarantee for multithreaded `CREATE UNIQUE` operations.

You would have to lock the two nodes in question. 
E.g. by removing an non-existant property.

```
MATCH (u:Airport {name:{1}}), (r:Airport {name:{2}})
REMOVE u._lock_, r._lock_
MERGE (u)-[:FLIGHT_TO]->(r) ON CREATE SET f.amount = {3}
```

PS: you also would want to use parameters for your airport names and the amount. Using prepared statement and `pst.setString(1,trip.getOutgoingAirport());`

Comment: Mmm...so I acquire the lock with a REMOVE? (Thanks for the advices)

Comment: I meant by remove something that doesn't exists?? Seriously?

Comment: Sorry :( there is no explicit lock statement in cypher (yet)

Comment: I tried with `"MATCH (u:Airport {name:{1}}), (r:Airport {name:{2}}) " +
                "REMOVE u._lock_, r._lock_ " +
                "MERGE (u)-[f:FLIGHT_TO]->(r) ON CREATE SET f.amount = {3}"` but I'm still getting some duplicates. I think it's the wrong approach. Should I use directly Java API?